# How to watch a Nokia Lumia Live Picture (Living Image) on a (Windows) PC?

Tags: camera, pictures, windows-8, windows-7

I have some nice live pictures/living pictures off my 730 Lumia phone.

They seem a bit like the pictures in Harry Potter (if you watched that..) anyway, I like the idea of a picture briefly coming to life.

To show them to friends, the screen is a bit small, so I want to view them on a Windows PC. I have 8.1 and 7 (on 7, the phone did not even connect, but I copied the files off on 8.1 and would now like to watch them on both Windows 7 and Windows 8.1).

I can watch the .jpg files, also, VLC plays the .thm (some video preview?) files, but, it does not combine them and also has not something like a slideshow mode, or one where I can easily click to the next image (and watch the current one).

How can I watch/play live pictures on a Windows Desktop PC?

**edit**
I am not looking for a phone-screen projector but rather for a picture viewer, like Irfanview, ACDSee, Photo Viewer or similar that supports live pictures.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, Project My Screen should do the trick.

Comment: That one did not work for me, I guess because I also don't get a usb connection for my phone on my Windows 7 64 computer - for whatever reason. Even though, I am not looking for a phone-screen projector but rather for a picture viewer, like Irfanview, VLC, ACDSee or similar that supports live picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have Windows 10 on your PC (not needed on phone) since the new "Photos" app supports the living images.

Comment: I tried this and it does not work at all. Tried the integrated photo app, did updates, it said "file type might not be supported" and that's it. Also, I tried both copied files and files from library (looks like MS auto-shares taken pictures, I did not even know). Also no additional resutls in Windows Store. How did you get it to work?